# How to get the current UIView in UIScroll?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Currently, I have a UIScrollView with X UIView as pages. I would like to know is there is way to get the UIView that;s is currently displayed?

```
    mScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    mScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        MyICalView* awesomeView=[[MyICalView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [mScroll addSubview:awesomeView];
        [awesomeView release];
    }
    mScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
    mScroll.delegate=self;
```

There any way to get the **awesomeView** currently displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
int pageIndex = mScroll.contentOffset.x/awesomeView.frame.size.width;
```

Just add these views to an array to access them or set their tag to 0,1,2